# ImageViews representing like and dislike not changing colors, nor is the new node being created in Firebase

Tags: java, android, json

I want to incorporate a **like** and **dislike** `ImageView` into my project much like the one Youtube has in the comments section. Upon selection they change colors from black to red, and only one can be selected. You can´t like and dislike a comment obviously, it has to be one or the other.

The way I currently have my Firebase is in the following way: When someone comments on a post the comments are saved and the JSON looks like this `Comments > PostId > CommentId > Publisher, Comment, CommentId`. I want to check if the `commentId` exists and if it does, then I want to create a new node under the root node that will look like this: `Comments Likes Dislikes > CommentId > Likes, Dislikes > UserId:true` (depending on which one they selected **like** or **dislike**.

The code that I have isn't turning the **like** `ImageView` red, nor is the new node being created. Not sure what I am missing here. Can Someone advise me if the way that I am thinking about this is correct, and perhaps the error in my code as to why the `ImageView` isn't turning from black to red `onClick`.

Not sure why I am having so much trouble with this... Am I thinking about the logic wrong? Is there a better way?

[image]

**CommentAdapter**

```
@Override


   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final Comment comment = mComment.get(position);

        commentLike(holder.commentLike);

        holder.commentLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Likes Dislikes")
                        .child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Likes Dislikes")
                        .child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
        });

 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView commentLike;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            commentLike = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_thumb_up_black);
        }
    }

 private void commentLike(ImageView imageView) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments").child(postid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                if (comment != null) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(comment.getCommentid()).exists()) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_red);
                        imageView.setTag("liked");
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_black);
                        imageView.setTag("like");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion.

Make Node under Root node named as "*Likes_Dislikes*". Whenever user likes or dislikes the comment make another node under "*Likes_Dislikes*" as a id of comment.
under that node made two nodes named as "*likes*" and "*dislikes*" and put the user id under that nodes according their actions.

To sum up your data base structure should look like this.

[image: Struvcture]

**Why am i suggesting this?**

Because you see, Fire-base download all the child nodes whenever their parent is referenced. Which means when your comment's likes/Dislikes gets increases you single comment nodes gets increases. Imagine having a post with 120 comments and each of having 120 likes and dislikes, Loading will be to slow.

So it is better to keep track of likes and dislikes into another separate node.
Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I uploaded the code, but I am still not getting the correct result. The Comment Likes Dislikes node is being created, with the structure ```Comment Likes Dislikes > CommentId > Likes > UserId: true```, but if I unlike the comment the value isn't getting removed... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you still facing the issue?

Comment: I made it work bro, thanks a lot. You helped a lot :)

Comment: One thing, I uploaded another question because I want if the user clicks the like ImageView he can't also click the dislike ImageView. He can only choose one or the other. If he selects one the other one unselects itself. Maybe you know how I can make it work?

Comment: let me have a look at it